# Why I can't connect my sockets from two PCs in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client-server

So far I have achieved making *server/client relations* on the same computer by parallelly running different java classes. As I don't want to overcomplicate this question, I will post my simplified code which works perfectly fine.

**Server:**

```
public class Server {
    public static final int PORT = 9090;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket (PORT);
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept ();
            System.out.println ("Client connected!");
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

}
```

**Client:**

```
public class Client {
        public static final int PORT = 9090;
        public static final String IP_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1";

    public static void main (String[] args)  {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket (IP_ADDRESS,PORT);

        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

}
```

After I run them, I get the expected output - console in class `Server` prints *"Client connected!"*.

Like any other curious programmer, I decided to try out the same program on my two laptops. One laptop has *client code*, while second has *server code*. Of course, I had to change **"127.0.0.1"** or **"localhost"** to ip address my *server laptop* has by typing on google `"what is my IP address"`. I just copied that **new IP address** into `IP_ADDRESS` variable and hoped it would work the same. Unfortunately, it didn't happen. My *client laptop* looks as if it never connected to *server laptop*, because *server laptop* never printed message *"Client connected!"*. What am I missing? It looks so easy, yet it doesn't work. Could someone help me solve this?

P.S. I don't want to share my IP address due to privacy reasons, but it was the first number that pops when any of you google: *what is my IP address*?

Comment: Is your server laptop exposed to the internet? I hope not. If your two computers are on the same local network you should try with a local address first. Search how to get your local ip on your operating system.

Comment: OgliWanFabi's answer helped as well. Can you tell me I must use local address and not the one I just quoted? The one I used is global, right?

Comment: Keep in mind this is a very basic and imprecise explanation, since I don't know your and your ISP's network configuration: the public address you got on google is your public one, but it's the one for your router. You were basically trying to open port 9090 on your router, not your server computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a local network, you don't have to take your public IP. You need to find your local IP (if you are on linux, a simple "ip a" and you'll have your IP address, [if you are on windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-your-ip-address-f21a9bbc-c582-55cd-35e0-73431160a1b9) )
If you are not on a local network, you could open your router' settings to open the 9090 port but I **STRONGLY** discourage you to do something like that for security reason.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Can you tell me why my approach didn't work? What am I missing? You want to say that port 9090 wasn't open and that was the only problem?

Comment: @Markus It doesn't work because NAT routers fundamentally break the Internet, and you have to know which side of the NAT router you're on, and which side the server is on, and use a different IP address depending, and sometimes you have to configure the NAT router (we call this port forwarding)... it's a mess. It works differently depending on whether the client and server are both on the same network or not.